# multiple image upload inside tinybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I want to build a multi upload image snippet inside the tinybox, but i can't, because some scripts send some errors, but if i use them outside of the tinybox this, works...

```
<script src="../main_elements/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<script src="../main_elements/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="../main_elements/js/jquery.knob.js"></script>
<script src="../main_elements/js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="../main_elements/js/script.js"></script>

 function loadSellForm() {
        TINY.box.show({
            html:'<div id="upload">' +
                '<div id="drop">' +
                    'Drop Here' +
                    '<a>Browse</a>' +
                    '<input id="mulfile" type="file" name="upl" multiple="multiple" />' +
                '</div>' +
                '<ul>' +
                '</ul>' +
            '</div>', animate: false, close: true, top: 70, opacity: 90)}; }
```

i'm trying to use this plugin: http://www.jotform.org/jquery/ajax-multi-file-upload-with-progress-bar/

**ERRORS:**

> Uncaught TypeError: Object function ( selector, context ) {       // The
>   jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
>         return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );     } has
>   no method 'widget'
>
> jquery.fileupload.js:44 Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has
>   no method 'fileupload'

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: latest, i think it's 2.0.3

Comment: Why do you have the function `loadSellForm` outside `<script>` tags?

Comment: it's inside, but not refered here, sorry